# string contains elongated words

Tags: python, string, character, python-itertools

My string is: "sooo dear how areeeee youuuuuu"

I want to check if the words in the string are elongated or not.

Elongated means: if the number of characters in the word is repeated more than twice so for example, too is not elongated but tooo is elongated.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_str = 'soooo hiiiii whyyyy done'
>>> print [[g[0], sum(1 for _ in g[1])] for g in itertools.groupby(my_str)]
[['s', 1], ['o', 4], [' ', 1], ['h', 1], ['i', 5], [' ', 1], ['w', 1], ['h', 1], 
['y', 4], [' ', 1], ['d', 1], ['o', 1], ['n', 1], ['e', 1]]
```

I want to display that sooo, areeeee and youuuuuu are elongated. I did individual character count but I want to check for every word to see if its elongated or not.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the output you want?

Comment: How do you know that a word is elongated? Is `too` supposed to count? This may not be a simple task.

Comment: Check for 3 consecutive equal chars should be ok? 2 consecutive chars is gonna be hard without checking in a dictionary.

Comment: What about `banana`? That has 3 `a`s in it.

Comment: @user2357112 it has to be continuous

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A regex comes to mind:

```
>>> my_str = 'soooo hiiiii whyyyy done'
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(.)\1{2}")
>>> [word for word in my_str.split() if regex.search(word)]
['soooo', 'hiiiii', 'whyyyy']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(.)    # Match any character, capture it in group number 1
\1{2}  # Try to match group number 1 here, twice.
```

Note that this algorithm will also find some unelongated words like `countessship` or `laparohysterosalpingooophorectomy`, but I guess those false positives are rare :)

Comment: m passing word one by one so first only 'soooo' then hiiiii so when i pass soooo it should give true .. how would the above code change

Comment: No the elongated condition still applies but like you have passed a list. I am providing the words in the list from a loop

Comment: Uh yes, and that's the condition you should then check. `for word in my_list: if regex.search(word): print("Booo!")`.

Comment: You can also do that without a loop, with findall.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `\w` instead of `.`.  Otherwise also things like `=====` look like elongated words.

Comment: @TimPietzcker if i want to count ? or ! more than 2 times in same regex, how can i do that? so for eg: why??? will be true but why!! false so either of them more than 2 times exists then true else false

Comment: @thg435 would you like to show how it can be done without a loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
def get_groups(word):
    return [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(word)]

print [word for word in my_str.split(' ') if any(len(x) > 2 for x in get_groups(word))]
```

Here's how it works: `get_groups` turns a word into groups. So `'sooo'` becomes `[['s'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]`.

We then filter all words from the given string if the length of any of the groups is more than two. This means you'll end up with all words that have three or more consecutive characters.

Comment: Will this consider strings like "ABABA" to be elongated? The OP didn't specify, but he may only care about continuous repetitions.

Comment: The OP has now specified that the repetitions have to be contiguous.

Comment: Thanks, I have now updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check by the sequence and compare length, **without importing anything**:

```
>>> filter(lambda word: len([letter for index,letter in enumerate(word) if index ==0 or word[index-1] != letter ]) == len( word), my_str.split(" "))
['done']

>>> filter(lambda word: len([letter for index,letter in enumerate(word) if index ==0 or word[index-1] != letter ]) != len( word), my_str.split(" "))
['soooo', 'hiiiii', 'whyyyy']
```

or **import itertools** and doing it with groupby :

```
>>> filter(lambda word: len([letter for letter,gp in itertools.groupby(word) ]) == len( word), my_str.split(" "))
['done']

>>> filter(lambda word: len([letter for letter,gp in itertools.groupby(word) ]) != len( word), my_str.split(" "))
['soooo', 'hiiiii', 'whyyyy']
```

this last solution permit tu use also ifilter instead of filter and iter on every good or bad words . useful for stream or very big string